# Using JQuery to delay loading of div, code not working in Chrome (window.onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm using the code below to delay the loading of a div until the entire web page is loaded. It works perfectly in Firefox and Safari (because they each have lines in the code to make sure it works specifically for each, I haven't tested IE yet), but not in Chrome (which should, I think, work with `window.onload`).

Could somebody please help me out with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function insertFB(){
    var html='<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell">Bob Caputo Living Well</a></blockquote></div></div>';
    $("#FB_PAGE").html(html);
}

if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", insertFB, false);
}

if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    var _timer = setinterval(function(){
        if(/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)){
            insertFB();
        }
    },10);
}

window.onload = insertFB();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly I'll answer specifically your question:

It's not working in Google Chrome, because you're using `setinterval`, and Javascript is a case-sensitive language. The correct name of the method is `setInterval`.

---

Besides that, your code is full of errors, you check for a method inside document, and don't use `else if` to check the others, so you always check all, and probably call the method you want two or more times.

The other thing is that you're using `setInterval` but you're never clearing the interval, so that thing is gonna run every 10ms forever.

And finally, the last thing, you're calling the `insertFB` function when you're trying to attach it to the `onload` event. You shouldn't be using parenthesis for that.

---

Take a look at [Can I use addEventListener?](http://caniuse.com/#search=addEventListener) and at [Can I use DOMContentLoaded?](http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded), and you'll see that it's supported by all major browsers, even some old ones, and you should only use another way, if you really need to support IE8 (nowadays it's unlikely).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I changed it to setInterval, but the only way the code would display/work is if I kept the parenthesis for the onload event but removed them from the insertFB above that one. Although, it still isn't working in Chrome for me. I'm still trying to get it to load after the entire page has loaded. In Chrome, it just loads it after the DOM has loaded and before the entire page has loaded. I'm not really experienced with code, and had a friend write this for me, so I'm trying to troubleshoot it and I greatly appreciate your help with this. Many thanks, Jared

Comment: Also, I will definitely take a look at and try to learn about your suggestions to see what improvements I can make. Thank you very much for those as well.

Comment: Also re: parenthesis. After changing setinterval to setInterval, it broke (I imagine what was supposed to happen due to my bad code). I tried removing the parenthesis for the insertFB that is on the onload event, and it stayed broken. I removed it from the one above too, and it was still broken. Both included, still broken. Only when the bottom one (onload) used parenthesis, then it worked (rather, it displayed in Chrome (even if it didn't work as intended, see above) and continued to work in Safari/Firefox).

Comment: So I did that but it still didn't work in Chrome (goal: loading after the entire page has loaded, not just DOM, like in the other browsers), and I modified the parenthesis which kind of broke it (when in combination with making setInterval work correctly), but found a way in which it made it go back to how it was before (working 100% in Safari/Firefox, displaying in Chrome, but not working). So I'm still trying to achieve that goal. Sorry for all the posts, I'm just trying to make it as clear as I can (perhaps I'm not, if so, sorry). Once again, I very much appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Comment: @JaredCaputo If you put that `script` tag inside your `head`, and you put only that code right below the function: `window.onload = insertFB;` - it should work in all browsers (and remove all the others).

Comment: tried that. Chrome is still just not liking it. Also, this code below seems to be doing the exact same thing as the code I was using before (also doesn't work with Chrome), so I've started using it instead/in place of the one I was using before, which is above: 

<script type="text/javascript">
var html='<div class="fb-page">...</div>';

$(window).load(function(){
    $("#fb-page").html(html);
});
</script>

Comment: @JaredCaputo can you put your entire html + js inside a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The website is http://www.bobcaputolivingwell.com/. Use Firefox or Safari, and you'll be able to tell that the Facebook module loads after the rest of the page loads (loader stops and displays content, seen either through the Developer tools or by just terminating the connection immediately after loading vs letting it continue). Use, Chrome, and you'll see it just loads the content before it's all done loading.

Comment: Interestingly, in the JS fiddle it doesn't load at all. In Firefox and Safari it works correctly, but at least it does indeed load in Chrome, even if not when it's supposed to...

Comment: Well, I can see too many problems in your page. First, if you don't want the FB module to load immeadiately, you must remove that: `<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell">Bob Caputo Living Well</a></blockquote></div></div>` from your HTML code.

Comment: Second, in your `$(window).load` method, you must get the correct `div` you want. You're using `$('#fb_page').html`, but there is no element with that ID inside the page. Javascript is case-sensitive, so you must use `$('#FB_PAGE').html`.

Comment: And finally, you're trying to add an empty `div` when the page is loaded, and that's not what you want. You should do: `var html = '<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell">Bob Caputo Living Well</a></blockquote></div></div>';` instead of that empty div.

Comment: But the thing is: if you want to load the facebook plugin only after the page loads, what you should do (instead of only putting the `div` when the page is loaded, is: let your HTML code exactly the way it is right now. Then, when the page loads, you add the Facebook script. I'll change create a plunker based on your fiddle for you, just a sec.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying...first comment: remove that form HTML in page. Done. Second: change $('#fb_page').html to $('#FB_PAGE').html. Third: change what I had before (var html='<div class="fb-page">...</div>';) to what you wrote. But now it's not loading under the Facebook title (remaining code there is <div id="FB_PAGE">. Which part did I screw up? Thanks again for your continued help :)

Comment: Oops, didn't see last comment. Thanks.

Comment: @JaredCaputo btw, your code has some errors (e.g: div tags inside the head tag; some tags that are open and never closed, etc)

Comment: Yay, that works! Thank you so, so much! I'm sure the code does have some errors, I can't modify all of it because it's Squarespace or I wouldn't be having this trouble (they have an annoying loader that doesn't display really anything until everything's loaded, which I put a loader over to make it look better, but that's why I'm delaying this FB module anyway -- the load times can be sporadic, depending on the connection.) But again, thank you so, so much!

Comment: @JaredCaputo if my answer was useful for you, please upvote it by clicking on the arrow, and mark it as the accepted, by clicking on the `V` right below the upvote/downvote arrows.